# Remove the background of my Custom WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

Hope you can help me on this inquiry I am trying to removed the white background of my Custom webpart that I have created so that its background will depend on the section background

[image]

when I check it on the dev tools it seems that this div has this class that is setting up the background.

class="ControlZone--emphasisBackground emphasisBackground-67"

Thanks for your help. and stay safe

[image]

Comment: Do you have any classes defined for the container that has the title? In your .scss file remove any background-color for that class. If you post the code for your component it will be easier for us to help!

Comment: You can use the CSS in your custom webpart to set the background of that class to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. there is no background or background-color on my webpart.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below CSS style to remove a background color from a specific class

```
.className

{
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ControlZone--emphasisBackground emphasisBackground-67 is out of webpart definition based on my testing(generated when you insert a webpart into modern page).

As [Script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) is a so helpful webpart in modern page customization, so you could deploy the webpart into your tenant and insert it into your page and override SharePoint CSS(answered by Mohamed El-Qassas).

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question. But I too faced this issue and I could fix this by adding below property to web part manifest file.

"supportsThemeVariants": true

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/supporting-section-backgrounds#making-your-web-part-theme-aware

> Making your web part theme aware:
>
> Update the manifest:
>
> You need to add a supportsThemeVariants property to the manifest of
> your webpart and set its value to true.